# how i can open the same website by using different ip addressess in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have to open the same website with different ip addressess for webscraping using python. I dont have detail knowledge about webscraping.I tried below but don't understand to me.What is the detail code for this???

```
def connectToSiteFunction(ip):
        # your code to bind ip (if it's a source) or connect to it (if it's a dst) 
        # and do your thing here

def connectAndWait():
    for ip in ips:
        t = threading.Thread(target=connectToSiteFunction, args=(ip,))
        yield t
        t.start()
        os.sleep(15)

threads = [t for t in connectAndWait()]
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your title and question seem to be at odds: If you know the address of the system, you can use one of a couple main ways of doing it:

1. Requests - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ this is a cool library system which makes it trivial to make web requests. Tons of examples on that page.
2. URLLib2 - https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html this is the method I would probably use if I didnt want to include 3rd party modules. you need to bea bit careful when encoding urls (use urllib to escape characters etc).

As for web-scraping (a terrible terrible name - call it HTML parsing!), have a look at Beautiful Soup ( http://beautiful-soup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ). this is only of use once you have retrieved the data using one of the methods above.

You also need to be aware that a lot of websites are aware of context - so what you see in your browser isnt what you will get back using these methods - you might have to make a bunch of requests (such as logging on) and maintaining cookies etc in the right order. But it all depends on what you're calling, and you havn't specified in the question.